# Django: Adding column to model giving error that the column doesn't exist

Tags: python, django, database, models

I have two models, each in separate apps of the same names:

```
class Vendor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, default='DEFAULT')
    serial_num = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)

class Node(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    persons = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

When I try `python3 manage.py makemigrations` I get the lengthy error below. I think the issue might be the migration files. Because `Home` has a foreign key to Person, `0001_initial.py` has dependency `('Person', '0007_auto_20180110_1827'),` and I am unable to add the serial_num column to Person. So I tried deleting the location column and adding the location column back in, then got the following error saying it doesn't recognize a column `location`.

How do I fix the issue? Also, let me know if I need to provide more info about the issue.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/karthikpullela/Desktop/Django-projects/QuikBikes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/karthikpullela/Desktop/Django-projects/QuikBikes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 303, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: vendor_vendor.location

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/karthikpullela/Desktop/Django-projects/QuikBikes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/karthikpullela/Desktop/Django-projects/QuikBikes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 365, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/karthikpullela/Desktop/Django-projects/QuikBikes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/karthikpullela/Desktop/Django-projects/QuikBikes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 332, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/Users/karthikpullela/Desktop/Django-projects/QuikBikes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/Users/karthikpullela/Desktop/Django-projects/QuikBikes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 351, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/karthikpullela/Desktop/Django-projects/QuikBikes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 73, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/Users/karthikpullela/Desktop/Django-projects/QuikBikes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 40, in check_url_namespaces_unique
    all_namespaces = _load_all_namespaces(resolver)
  File "/Users/karthikpullela/Desktop/Django-projects/QuikBikes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 57, in _load_all_namespaces
    url_patterns = getattr(resolver, 'url_patterns', [])
  File "/Users/karthikpullela/Desktop/Django-projects/QuikBikes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 36, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/karthikpullela/Desktop/Django-projects/QuikBikes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 536, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/Users/karthikpullela/Desktop/Django-projects/QuikBikes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 36, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/karthikpullela/Desktop/Django-projects/QuikBikes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 529, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/Users/karthikpullela/Desktop/Django-projects/QuikBikes/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/karthikpullela/Desktop/Django-projects/QuikBikes/QuikBikes/QuikBikes/urls.py", line 28, in <module>
    path('node/', include('node.urls')),
  File "/Users/karthikpullela/Desktop/Django-projects/QuikBikes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/Users/karthikpullela/Desktop/Django-projects/QuikBikes/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/karthikpullela/Desktop/Django-projects/QuikBikes/QuikBikes/node/urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "/Users/karthikpullela/Desktop/Django-projects/QuikBikes/QuikBikes/node/views.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .forms import AddNodeForm
  File "/Users/karthikpullela/Desktop/Django-projects/QuikBikes/QuikBikes/node/forms.py", line 7, in <module>
    class AddNodeForm(forms.Form):
  File "/Users/karthikpullela/Desktop/Django-projects/QuikBikes/QuikBikes/node/forms.py", line 10, in AddNodeForm
    for person in Vendor.objects.all():
  File "/Users/karthikpullela/Desktop/Django-projects/QuikBikes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 272, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/Users/karthikpullela/Desktop/Django-projects/QuikBikes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1179, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/Users/karthikpullela/Desktop/Django-projects/QuikBikes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 54, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "/Users/karthikpullela/Desktop/Django-projects/QuikBikes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1063, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/karthikpullela/Desktop/Django-projects/QuikBikes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/karthikpullela/Desktop/Django-projects/QuikBikes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/Users/karthikpullela/Desktop/Django-projects/QuikBikes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/Users/karthikpullela/Desktop/Django-projects/QuikBikes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/karthikpullela/Desktop/Django-projects/QuikBikes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/Users/karthikpullela/Desktop/Django-projects/QuikBikes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/karthikpullela/Desktop/Django-projects/QuikBikes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 303, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column: vendor_vendor.location
(QuikBikes) Karthiks-MacBook-Pro:QuikBikes karthikpullela$ python3 manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/karthikpullela/Desktop/Django-projects/QuikBikes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/karthikpullela/Desktop/Django-projects/QuikBikes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 303, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: vendor_vendor.location

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/karthikpullela/Desktop/Django-projects/QuikBikes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/karthikpullela/Desktop/Django-projects/QuikBikes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 365, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/karthikpullela/Desktop/Django-projects/QuikBikes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/karthikpullela/Desktop/Django-projects/QuikBikes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 332, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/Users/karthikpullela/Desktop/Django-projects/QuikBikes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/Users/karthikpullela/Desktop/Django-projects/QuikBikes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 351, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/karthikpullela/Desktop/Django-projects/QuikBikes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 73, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/Users/karthikpullela/Desktop/Django-projects/QuikBikes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 40, in check_url_namespaces_unique
    all_namespaces = _load_all_namespaces(resolver)
  File "/Users/karthikpullela/Desktop/Django-projects/QuikBikes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 57, in _load_all_namespaces
    url_patterns = getattr(resolver, 'url_patterns', [])
  File "/Users/karthikpullela/Desktop/Django-projects/QuikBikes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 36, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/karthikpullela/Desktop/Django-projects/QuikBikes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 536, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/Users/karthikpullela/Desktop/Django-projects/QuikBikes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 36, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/karthikpullela/Desktop/Django-projects/QuikBikes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 529, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/Users/karthikpullela/Desktop/Django-projects/QuikBikes/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/karthikpullela/Desktop/Django-projects/QuikBikes/QuikBikes/QuikBikes/urls.py", line 28, in <module>
    path('node/', include('node.urls')),
  File "/Users/karthikpullela/Desktop/Django-projects/QuikBikes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/Users/karthikpullela/Desktop/Django-projects/QuikBikes/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/karthikpullela/Desktop/Django-projects/QuikBikes/QuikBikes/node/urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "/Users/karthikpullela/Desktop/Django-projects/QuikBikes/QuikBikes/node/views.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .forms import AddNodeForm
  File "/Users/karthikpullela/Desktop/Django-projects/QuikBikes/QuikBikes/node/forms.py", line 7, in <module>
    class AddNodeForm(forms.Form):
  File "/Users/karthikpullela/Desktop/Django-projects/QuikBikes/QuikBikes/node/forms.py", line 10, in AddNodeForm
    for person in Vendor.objects.all():
  File "/Users/karthikpullela/Desktop/Django-projects/QuikBikes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 272, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/Users/karthikpullela/Desktop/Django-projects/QuikBikes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1179, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/Users/karthikpullela/Desktop/Django-projects/QuikBikes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 54, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "/Users/karthikpullela/Desktop/Django-projects/QuikBikes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1063, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/karthikpullela/Desktop/Django-projects/QuikBikes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/karthikpullela/Desktop/Django-projects/QuikBikes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/Users/karthikpullela/Desktop/Django-projects/QuikBikes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/Users/karthikpullela/Desktop/Django-projects/QuikBikes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/karthikpullela/Desktop/Django-projects/QuikBikes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/Users/karthikpullela/Desktop/Django-projects/QuikBikes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/karthikpullela/Desktop/Django-projects/QuikBikes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 303, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column: vendor_vendor.location
```

EDIT: This is `forms.py` for Node.

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from vendor.models import Vendor

class AddNodeForm(forms.Form):

    VENDOR_CHOICES = [('none', '---------')]
    for person in Vendor.objects.all():
        VENDOR_CHOICES.append((person, person))

    node_vendor = forms.ChoiceField(label='Vendor', choices=VENDOR_CHOICES)
```

Answer (score 3):

You have some code at class level in AddNodeForm that is performing a query. Since that code is called on import, it is being executed before the migration can even have a chance to run.

You should not do queries at that level - or indeed any significant logic. Anything like this should be within a method.

Comment: So I added the code for forms.py, which has AddNodeForm. Should I put the code for VENDOR_CHOICES within a function, then return the variable?

Comment: Also, how do I get it to work then, assuming that the code goes through forms.py before going through the migrations for `Vendor`?

Comment: You should use a ModelChoiceField, which accepts a queryset refer than a list of choices.